# Long summation question, including sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, proof-writing

I have a really long question I'm absolutely stuck on, I don't even know where to begin:

Given:

$n \in \mathbb{Z}, \geq 2$

let $S$ be the set of all nonempty subsets of {2,3,...,n}. For each $S_i \in S$ let $P_i$ be thje product of the elements of $S_i$ prove or disprove:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2^{n-1}-1} P_i = \frac{(n+1)!}{2} -1$

Comment: Shouldn't the upper limit of the sum be $2^n-1$?

Comment: Your $\Phi$ in the definition of $S$ should probably be $\emptyset$, which you get with \emptyset and the $N$ at the end should probably be $n$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Or even better (my preference, anyway), $\varnothing$, which you get with \varnothing .

Comment: The power set has $2^n$ elements, so excluding the empty set leaves $2^n-1$. The index of the sum should take on $2^n-1$ values. Your correction was still wrong. And, technically, you haven't specified how the elements of the power set are to be enumerated. You could just index the sum by the elements of $S$ itself: $\sum_{A\in S}P_A$, with $P_A =\prod_{x\in A}x$

Comment: Edited it further to match with the book, this is the problem as written.

Comment: (This is what you call a really long question?) One possible way to start is to verify the statement for small values of $n$ like 2, 3, and 4, and see whether any pattern arises.

Comment: I'm confused by the limit, if it's stating "$2^{n-1}-1$ would that mean the base case would be $n = 2$, therefore:

$\frac{(1+1)!}{2} -1 = 0$

Comment: The base case is $n=2$, and it’s fine: $$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{2-1}-1}P_i=P_1=2\;,$$ and $\frac{(2+1)!}2-1=\frac62-1=2$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You can prove it quite straightforwardly by induction on $n$ if you notice that the non-empty subsets of $\{2,\ldots,n,n+1\}$ are of three kinds:

- non-empty subsets of $\{2,\ldots,n\}$;
- $S\cup\{n+1\}$, where $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\{2,\ldots,n\}$; and
- $\{n+1\}$.

Comment: The vandals are out again.

Answer (score -1):

For a set $S$, consider the product $\prod_{x \in S}(1+x)$. Each term in this expansion is the product of elements of one proper subset of $S$, except for the term $1$. Applying this to your set and simplifying gives the answer.